# C# method not working when called via published WebAPI

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-web-api

I have simplified my method for testing purposes. It works fine when running locally in VS 2013 debug mode.

Here is my APIController:

```
    namespace Citizen.Hub.WebAPI.Controllers
{
    public class ReportsController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public void RunAttendanceByYear(string school, string fromdate, string todate)
        {
            var runreport = new AttendanceReports();

            runreport.WebAPITest(school, fromdate, todate);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my simplified method for testing:

```
public void WebAPITest(string school, string fromdate, string todate)
        {
            //Create new instance of Excel, Workbook and Worksheet
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
            Sheets xlSheets = xlWorkbook.Sheets as Sheets;

            //Create new worksheet for school
            Worksheet xlNewSheet = (Worksheet)xlSheets.Add(xlSheets[1], Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            //Worksheet headers
            xlNewSheet.Cells[1, "A"] = "School";
            xlNewSheet.Cells[1, "B"] = "From";
            xlNewSheet.Cells[1, "C"] = "To";

            //Populate sheet with data
            xlNewSheet.Cells[2, "A"] = school;
            xlNewSheet.Cells[2, "B"] = fromdate;
            xlNewSheet.Cells[2, "C"] = todate;

            //Define filename and file path
            string fileName = string.Format(@"{0}\Test.xlsx", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory));

            //Save this data as a file
            xlWorkbook.SaveAs(fileName);

            //Quit Excel application
            xlApp.Quit();

            //Release COM objects
            if (xlApp != null)
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

            if (xlWorkbook != null)
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);

            xlApp = null;
            xlWorkbook = null;
            GC.Collect();
        }
```

Works fine when ran in debug mode and outputs "Test.xlsx" to the desktop.

When I publish the WebAPI locally and assign it port number 1111, it just doesn't want to work. I believe IIS is configured correctly because when I browse to it I get the default VS WebAPI home page.

My call is: `http://localhost:1111/api/reports?school=TestSchool&fromdate=2013-09-01&todate=2014-02-07`

I get an 'Aborted' result in IE and Response is HTTP/1.1 204 No Content

Any advice? Thanks.

RouteConfig:

```
public class RouteConfig 
{ 
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) 
    { 
         routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); 
         routes.MapRoute( name: "Default", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
         defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =UrlParameter.Optional});
    } 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried giving a type of response to the browser e.g. JSon just to say it's completed, so the browser sees some response?

Comment: can you show us the routing config ?

Comment: @PaulZahra If I change the controller method to public string and return "ok", it returns it as jSON and Result is 200, but my runreport.WebAPITest() method still doesn't work.

Comment: @Cybermaxs-Betclic Here is the RouteConfig:

`public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }`

Comment: To what Desktop folder should the IIS account write to? Basically return the generated document and let the user save them

Comment: Have you run fiddler or soapui or WireShark? What are they saying?

Comment: Shouldn't you somewhere be doing something like this...             config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "WebAPITest",
                routeTemplate: "WebAPITest/{controller}..."); ... and then calling with something like http://localhost:1111/WebAPITest/Reports? ...

Comment: Maybe, there's an issue with access rights? When you run your api from VS in debug mode, it's running under your account, but when you publish your api, ti's running under different account.

Comment: @PaulZahra The routing is definitely correct as it runs perfectly locally

Comment: @Sascha I need to output the file in this manner as in the project I'm working on, the file will be placed in a SharePoint UNC path.

Comment: @insomnium_ I too was thinking about permissions. Can anybody offer advice on changing these within IIS?

Comment: I think Sascha is right.  Your code is trying to save to desktop, but is running under IIS account which has no desktop and has very limited rights as to what it can access on the system.  Have it save to a predefined folder, and make sure that folder gives rights for whatever account IIS is running under to save files there (try local first before going UNC as UNC can give additional headache).  That desktop save just doesn't look right and is likely what's giving you grief.  Additionally, use log4net to capture steps all the way, and you'll probably see where the code fails and why.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with IIS and permissions. I basically followed the steps in this link here:
http://www.bloing.net/2011/01/how-to-make-iis7-play-nice-with-office-interop/